# ValueError: Unknown initializer for using keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got an error while loading my trained model. My model is about stereo vision, so I used both from tensorflow and keras( not tf.keras).

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import keras.layers as L
import keras.backend as B
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as B_
import keras.activations as A
import tensorflow as tf
```

Among the code lines I have this :

```
f_disp = 200

f_d = L.Conv2D(filters=f_disp, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')(f_uuu)
f_d = L.BatchNormalization()(f_d)
f_d = L.ReLU()(f_d)

f_d = L.Conv2D(filters=f_disp, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')(f_d)
f_d = L.BatchNormalization()(f_d)
f_d = L.ReLU()(f_d)

def disp_filter(shape, dtype=None):
    kernel = (np.array(range(f_disp),dtype=np.float32))
    kernel = np.tile(kernel,(shape[0]*shape[1]))
    kernel = np.reshape(kernel,(shape[0],shape[1],f_disp,1))
    print(shape,kernel.shape)
    assert kernel.shape == shape
    return tf.Variable(kernel,dtype=np.float32)
def sq(x):
    sig = A.softmax(x,axis=-1)
    f_f = L.Conv2D(filters = 1, kernel_size=(1,1),kernel_initializer=disp_filter,strides=1,padding='same',trainable=False)(sig)

    sqx = B.squeeze(f_f,-1)
    return sqx
f_sq = L.Lambda(sq)(f_d)
print(f_sq.shape)
return f_sq
```

Since my layer has more than 300 lines I took only this part.

However When I tried to load model, it outputs error message.

```
srst = tf.keras.models.load_model(route_weight, compile=True, custom_objects={'disp_filter':disp_filter,'A':keras.activations,'L':keras.layers,'B': keras.backend,'B_':keras.backend.tensorflow_backend,'tf':tf,'maxdsp':192})#,'A':keras.activations})
srst.summary()
```

This is my load_model code and :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/eps/venv/test_srstereo.py", line 96, in <module>
srst = tf.keras.models.load_model(route_weight, compile=True, custom_objects={'disp_filter':disp_filter,'A':keras.activations,'L':keras.layers,'B': keras.backend,'B_':keras.backend.tensorflow_backend,'tf':tf,'maxdsp':192})#,'A':keras.activations})
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 146, in load_model
return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 168, in load_model_from_hdf5
custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 102, in deserialize
printable_module_name='layer')
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 191, in deserialize_keras_object
list(custom_objects.items())))
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 906, in from_config
config, custom_objects)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1852, in reconstruct_from_config
process_node(layer, node_data)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1799, in process_node
output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 842, in __call__
outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 795, in call
return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\stereo_net.py", line 268, in sq
x2_u = L.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x2,x2_u])
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 484, in __init__
**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 117, in __init__
self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 518, in get
return deserialize(config)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 510, in deserialize
printable_module_name='initializer')
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 140, in deserialize_keras_object
': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown initializer: disp_filter
```

I cannot understand why the error message     **ValueError: Unknown initializer: disp_filter**
occurs since I have never experienced this type of error when I made my network using CNN and backend only. Please tell me what I missed

Comment: Where does `disp_filter` come from? Is it supposed to be `Disparity Filter`?

Comment: @yudhiesh In the second block, there is def disp_filter(shape, dtype=None)

Comment: I guess you cannot use the function directly as argument here. Try to do something like `disp_filter = disp_filter(...)` before usage in function args.

Comment: Are you loading a subclassed model ?

Comment: @andrey what it subclassed model ? Im sorry but I dont have firm concept of it.

Comment: @MooNChilDSong did you create a class inherited from tf.keras.Model ? Or your model is created with Sequential or Functional API ?

Comment: @Andrey My model is created with functional API of keras, since I thought it is best to build shared network.